# How do you remove Metro apps from Alt-Tab?

Tags: windows-8.1, alt-tab

Is there a program or setting to prevent Metro apps from showing up in the Alt-Tab display? And if not, is there a specific Windows DLL file or EXE file that handles Alt-Tab functionality?

Comment: the "C:\Windows\System32\AltTab.dll" handles this. But I have no idea how to do remove them from ALT-tap.

Comment: Thanks, I tried overwriting it with the windows 7 AltTab.dll and it had the same effect as LAlt + (tap RALT) + tab, I'll have to see about finding or making a patch later.